# How to create an empty string using _string_ method to insert sparse vector data

Tags: python, methods

I have this assignment where I would like to create an empty string where sparse vector data would be stored at. I need to check whether the key index exists in the sparse vector (self.data).  If not, I need to store, in the empty string, the sparse vector and zero values. The error I am getting is *TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type NoneType)*. This is my code:

```
    class SparceVector(object):

def __init__(self, n):
    self.length = n
    self.data = {}

def __str__(self):
    outstr = None or ""
    assert 0 <= key and key < self.length
    try:
        outstr = ((str(key), str(value)) for key,value in self.data.items())
        return  
    except KeyError:
        return 0
    return "The sparce vector is {}".format(outstr)

def __len__(self):
    return self.legth

def __getitem__(self, key):
    assert 0 <= key and key < self.length
    try:
        return self.data[key]
    except KeyError:
        return 0
        return self.data[key]

def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    assert 0 <= key and key < self.length 
    if value != 0:     
        self.data[key] = value

def nonzeros(self):
    return self.data

def __add__(self, other):
    assert self.length == other.length
    merged = SparceVector(self.length)
    c = {key:value for key, value in self.data.items()}
    for key, value in other.data.items():
        try:
            c[key] += value
        except KeyError:
            c[key] = value
    merged.data = c
    merged.nonzeros()
    return merged

def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.data)

def key(self):
    return self.data.key()

def items(self):
    return self.data.items()

def values(self):
    return self.data.values()
```

Comment: The method `__str__` is supposed to return a string. That's literally its entire purpose. In your implementation, you alternately return `None`, and integer, or a string. Why is this necessary? Why are you actually using `__str__` for conveying this complex information, instead of a purpose-built method?

Comment: Hello, I have to state that I am a beginner in python. I originally used the __string__ method to print the expression "The sparce vector is {}".format(self.data)". My professor told me that I need to create an empty string in the  __string__ method to store sparse vector data. I cannot really understand why he asked me that. I though that setitem and getitem methods are doing that by storing them in a dictionary. Nevertheless, do you have any other suggestions?